# python 3.x I want to write a code that with random

Tags: python-3.x, random

```
import random
score=2
heads=1
tails=2


while score>=2:
    a= input("Heads or tails?")
    if random.randint(heads,tails)==a:
        score +=1
        print("Yes it's correct!. Now your score is:",score)

    else:
        score -=1
        print("Fail.now your score is:",score)


print("GAMEOVER You Lose ")
```

Guys I tried to write a code that when input asks to user if he/she writes down heads or tails python gives a random decision or whatever(heads or tails).
But I couldn't manage to do it with strings. what I'am trying to do is I want to write tails for a input and if its true my score will be 2 and it goes till score become 1
BTW I'm sorry about my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something with a **minimal change of your code**. The exact method you were trying to perform cannot be done in python without using a datatype.

Here I am using a dictionary called 'dict'. It is basically a key value pair. And uses anything inside double quotes i.e. " " as an index. Syntactically similar to arrays in C++ but not limited to only integer indices.

```
import random
score=2
heads=1
tails=2
dict {"Heads":1,"Tails":2,"heads":1,"tails":2} # Handles both lower and upper case

while score>=2:
    a= input("Heads or tails?")
    if random.randint(heads,tails)==dict[a]:
        score +=1
        print("Yes it's correct!. Now your score is:",score)

    else:
        score -=1
        print("Fail.now your score is:",score)


print("GAMEOVER You Lose ")
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to this is instead of letting random choose a number, let it choose from a couple of possible options using `random.choice`

```
import random
possible_results = ["heads", "tails"]
guess = input("Heads or Tails?").lower()
result = random.choice(possible_results)
if guess == result:
    #rest of your code
```

This has the extra bonus of added readability as and you can even expand it to choose from an even bigger list of results.

Answer (score 0):

we can't get random strings but we can do the same thing in this way:

```
import random
score=2
heads=1
tails=2


while score>=2:
    a= input("Heads or tails?")
    predict = random.randint(0,1)
    if predict == 0:
        answer = "Heads"
    else:
        answer = "Tails"
    if answer == a:
         score +=1
         print("Yes it's correct!. Now your score is:",score)

    else:
        score -=1
        print("Fail.now your score is:",score)


 print("GAMEOVER You Lose ")
```